# Batch file Looping through files in a set directory returning errors

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to loop through and print a list of all files in a directory, the directory is being set by 2 different arguments, but I keep getting the following error

`The syntax of the command is incorrect`

I'm not really sure where im going wrong though as when i echo out the variables they are echoing correctly.

My code is as follows;

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "parent=C:\Users\Test\script\files"
set "addon=GROWTH"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%X in ("%parent%\%addon%\*") do (
    echo %%~dpnX
)

endlocal
endlocal
```

So basically, i just want it to list all the files in the `C:\Users\Test\script\files\GROWTH` directory.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your script, as posted, _although all the `SetLocal` and `EndLocal` lines are unnecessary_, doesn't appear to have any issues. Can you please show the actual script, _or missing part of this one_, which is outputting the error.

Comment: Im afraid thats the entire script ... I must be missing something

Comment: Remove the `@echo off` line and add a new line, `pause`, to the bottom, then run it again. Copy and paste the result into your question as an edit. I'm assuming that your real script, _despite your comment above_, has an error with whatever you've neglected to show us within the `do` section. It is likely that you're using the returned metavariable without doublequoting it to protect spaces and/or other problematic characters.

Comment: Possible file encoding issue? though I think that would yield a different error message. Else perhaps there is a hidden character causing problems. Copy the code that you posted directly from your question, and paste it into a brand new ASCII text file named TEST.BAT, and run it. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not have any issues as it is working. I suspect that you are only having issues with the locations of your opening parentheses So to see if this is indeed the case, try this one. we do not need the parentheses as it is a single command to follow the `for` statement:

```
@echo off
set "parent=C:\Users\Test\script\files"
set "addon=GROWTH"

for %%X in ("%parent%\%addon%\*") do echo %%~dpnX
```

Comment: Hmmm thats strange, this seems to have fixed it ... Thank you